# Add class to td except first and second coloumn of each row

Tags: jquery

```
$(".csstablelisttd").live('mousedown', function (e)
{    
    var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    var colIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();  
    $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).addClass('csstdhighlight');
});
```

I have to add class to td except first and second coloumn of each row

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65S7N/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (colIndex == 0 || colIndex == 1)
return;
```

Do this

Answer (score 3):

Write it as -

```
$('tr').find('td:gt(1)').addClass('csstdhighlight');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dTCjH/2/)

This will add class to all TDs in each row except first two

Comment: Specifically greater than index 1. :)

Comment: Hi dipak can i ask u one quetion

Comment: i have to get start time and end time....start time can get on which cell drag start and end time can get on which cell drag ends ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) . This will select td which will greater than column index

```
$('table tr').find('td:gt(1)').css('color','red');​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JzG5D/)

Comment: i am adding class on column index and row index

Comment: also select by something like `td:first-child` and  `td:nth-child(2)`

Comment: @lax: `gt` will select from third `td` except first and second

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/65S7N/4/    see in fiddle i have t seelct only class not time slot